# BigQuery: Array specified for non-repeated field

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I want to upload JSON data to a BigQuery table. The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    a: [1,2,3]
}
```

But I am getting this error: `Array specified for non-repeated field a`

Comment: Looks like repeated field, is what I needed here.. Thanks for this platform this really gets you.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is how you define the schema. In case you are providing the schema and you wanted to have a repeated field, the should look like the following:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
        },
        {
            "name": "a",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "number",
                    "type": "NUMERIC",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

And your data should be processed to be like this:
```

```
{
    "id": "23849996594630040",
    "a": [
        {"number": 1}, 
        {"number": 2}, 
        {"number": 3}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DDL for table that accepts that JSON structure:

```
create table `sample_table` (
    a ARRAY<INT64>
);
```

Note that:

- Each one of those JSON represents a row in the table.
- The above DDL will produce a table with a single column of **Field name** `a`, **Type** `INTEGER` and **Mode** `REPEATED`.

If you are using the API, the JSON representation of the table's schema may look like this:

```
{
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"a",
            "type":"INTEGER",
            "mode":"REPEATED",
            <...>
        }
    ]
}
```